# Accessing refs of a sibling component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this situation where I have two sibling components, where the first component appears as follows:

```
class X extends Component {

   someRenderMethod(){
       //does something 
   }  

   render(){
      return(
          <div class="xyz">
             <p>some text</p>
             <div class="the-div-i-want-render" ref="one">
                   {this.someRenderMethod}
             </div>
          </div> 
      )
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(){
   //
}

function mapDispatchToProps(){
  //
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(X);
```

My second sibling component is as follows:

```
    import X from './x'

    export class Y extends Component {

       render(){
          return (
               <div>
                  <div>
                         //Here I want to render the div inside   //component X
                         // In the real case, I show the div here in                   //response to a button click event. 
                        //I have tried to import the component and get           //the refs of X, but that is not working. 
                  </div>

               </div>

           )
       }
    }
```

I have tried to import the component X into Y and get the refs of X, but that is not working (the ref object is always null). Is there any other way where I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

By importing `X` you are just importing the class for the component. Not the instance of it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming))

A components `refs` are not available until the component was mounted (rendered once). Therefore the first time you have access to the `refs` object is in the components `componentDidMount` life cycle function.

To address your problem: Component `X` needs to communicate its `refs` up the tree to a parent component. The parent renders both, `X` and `Y`. When `X` was mounted you can call a callback from your parent container passing the `refs` as an argument. The parent can now react to this and pass the `refs` object down to `Y` via `props`. You can make use of local state `this.state/setState` to easily achieve re-rendering of `Y` after `X` did mount.